# why 18-digits of tweet ID (should be 64 digit) using twitteR in R

Tags: r, twitter

Hi I'm using twitteR package in R to connect with twitter API.

I learned that tweet ID should be a 64-digit unsigned number, and people usually convert is to a string because 64-digit number is sometimes not supported. Larger tweet ID implies newer tweet. (Correct me if i'm wrong please)

Using twitteR I read tweet ID of 18 digits (already string, converted by a wrapped-up function twListToDF). Anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```
#install.packages("twitteR")
#install.packages('httr')
library(twitteR)
library(httr)

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret) #put your own key in pls

t = searchTwitter('Staples', n=500, lang='en')

t.df = twListToDF(t)
#dim(t.df)
#names(t.df)
text = t.df[ ,'text']
t.df[1,'id']
```

Comment: thanks @cory I figured I shouldn't put the key there, but then I saw some people complaining code irreproducible...

Comment: yeah, I think you can make a reproducible example with just an 18 digit integer... don't worry about the twitter library stuff.

Comment: do you mean 18-digit tweet ID will just work? (or are you talking about consumer_key, consumer_secret?) @cory thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `gmp` package for dealing with large integers.

```
library("gmp")
num <- as.bigz("123456789012345678")
> add.bigz(num, 1)
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 123456789012345679
> add.bigz(num, 1) > num
[1] TRUE
```